# WHat is the use of @Valid when @NonNull does the job for us?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

**Code in controller -**

```
@PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee saveEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
    }
```

**Entity Object -**

```
@NotNull(message = "Department must not be null")
@Column(name = "department")
private String department;
```

Suppose I pass an item with a null department field. @NonNull will throw an exception in that case. But I have seen @Valid being used for the same purpose. Can somebody elaborate why @Valid needs to be used in addition to @NonNull?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `@Valid` and send null department?

Comment: Yes. I get an exception. But just a different one.

Comment: I guess in that case you get one from the db saying you can't have null inserted. `@Valid` is needed to tell SpringBoot to automatically bootstraps the default JSR 380 implementation — like Hibernate Validator — and to validate the argument. Without it `@NotNull` is not considered.

Comment: Edited the question. Now when I remove Valid annotation and send a null department, I get Department must not be null as the output. So how is this getting verified in the db? I think this is getting verified using NonNull annotation

Comment: Then you probably have `@Validated` or `@Valid` annotation in the entity itself. Validation doesn't kick in without that.

Comment: I was testing from Postman

Comment: Is NonNull of no use without @Valid according to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240188/discussion-between-vl4d1m1r4-and-christian-alderson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit the `@Valid` Spring will omit the validation on the web layer. Which basically means your controller, will not trigger validation. Validation is done by the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` when an `@Valid(adted)` annotation is found on an `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestBody` annotated method argument.

JPA will also use a configured validator and trigger validation as well. So a validation exception will be thrown upon writing into the database.  You can disable this with `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none` in your `application.properties` (or the YAML equivalent). When disabling both no validation will be done. In that case you only hope is a database constraint that the column isn't allowed to be `null`.

So validation is still done **but** the location where the validation is done is different. Due to the difference you will also get a different exception.

You have to wonder do you really want to do this somewhere upon persisting the entity with the risk of having executed some complex/time consuming business logic, or quickly upon submission of the form.

Answer (score 1):

So that the object can be validated in the Controller layer you need `@Valid` (or `@Validated`) to trigger its validation.

You can read more about this on the following online resources:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated

On which you can read:

> Of course, the most relevant part is the use of the @Valid annotation.
> When Spring Boot finds an argument annotated with @Valid, it
> automatically bootstraps the default JSR 380 implementation —
> Hibernate Validator — and validates the argument.